# Did the Hutter Prize help research in artificial intelligence in any way?

Tags: research, history, data-compression

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hutter_Prize&oldid=1006878582) states:

> - The Hutter Prize is a cash prize funded by Marcus Hutter which rewards data compression improvements on a specific 1 GB English text file.
> - The goal of the Hutter Prize is to encourage research in artificial intelligence (AI). The organizers believe that text compression and AI are equivalent problems.

Did the Hutter Prize help research in artificial intelligence in any way?